# What permission do I need to see a set of API in the API restrictions section in Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I want to limit my API key to a set of APIs. However I don't have the permission to see the list of APIs.The dropdown is simply blank. What permission do I need to see the content?

I currently have the `serviceusage.apiKeysAdmin` permission.

[image: API restrictions - empty dropdown]

Comment: A completely uneducated guess, but should your existing APIs not first be  configured/extended, or protected with API restrictions and accept/support authentication before you can create a key that grants access to those APIs?

Comment: It's unclear because the service|method doesn't appear in Developer Tools but ... it should be enumerating the services using [Service Usage](https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/reference/rest/) API and you can get|list the services with [`roles/serviceusage.serviceUsageViewer`](https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/access-control#predefined_roles)

Answer (score 0):

The `serviceusage.apiKeysAdmin` permission you currently have is not sufficient to view the list of APIs associated with the API key.

You need the `serviceusage.services.list` permission. It will allow you to list all the services available in a project, which includes the APIs that the API key can access.

By granting the `serviceusage.services.list` permission to your user or service account, you should be able to see the list of APIs associated with the API key. This can be done by assigning the appropriate IAM role to your user or service account, such as the `roles/serviceusage.serviceUsageViewer` role, which includes the necessary permission to list services.

Once you have the required permission, you should be able to view the list of APIs associated with the API key in the Cloud Console or via the API Keys API.